# How to create a custom tag with attribute as variable?

Tags: jsp, taglib

I know how to create custom tags with attributes something like:

```
<my-prefix:mytag count = "5">
content
</my-prefix:mytag>
```

But I dont know how to create a custom tag with attribute as variable like the `<c:set>` tag in JSP Core Tag Library.
Something like:

```
<my-prefix:mytag my-var="count-loop" count = "5">
content
</my-prefix:mytag>
```

Then I can use:

```
${count-loop} => output "5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have read the [Custom Tags in JSP Pages](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnalj/index.html) tutorial, so you know how to declare the tag attributes and handler. Then, suggesting your attributes are `myVar` and `count`, and you have corresponding fields (`String myVar`, `int count`) and setters (`void setMyVar(String myVar)`, `void setCount(int count)`) in your handler, all you need to do, is to add a page context attribute in the handler's `doTag()` method:

```
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
  // ...
  getJspContext().setAttribute(myVar, count);
  // ...
}
```

and you can use it in EL **after** the tag, so

```
<my-prefix:mytag myVar="count-loop" count="5"></my-prefix:mytag>
Count: ${count-loop}
```

will produce following output:

```
Count: 5
```